# jQuery tabs with dynamic pages

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-tabs

I have a little problem with jQuery Tabs.
I get it to work well. But when I open the pages dynamically (eg. I click to open a new tab for a product) it may be several tabs open to different products. But each side has of course the same id and so on (eg. div tags). This means that when I change something on another tab so it's affecting the other tabs.

How do you solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have some example code you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a scalar ID (1,2,3,4,5, ecc) for these DIVs and just store the "reference ID" in another field.

The use of the same ID for different nodes is just a **bad** practice. It also breaks the validation of your document.

Take a look at the [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method on jQuery that allow you to store data in an arbitrary way